# HTML Input field required pattern

Tags: html

I have 2 input fields, one is text type and the other email type.

Code for the text :

```
<input required pattern=".*\S+.*" title="This field is required" type="text" name="Name" id="id1">
```

for the email :

```
<input required pattern=".*\S+.*" title="This field is required" type="email" name="Email" id="email">
```

I want to restrict users leaving fields only with white spaces or special characters. It works on pc, but when i am accesing it from android it doesnt work. It lets me use white spaces. The code for the text type can be made of white space

edit: It seems that the problem was even on pc with white space on the input field of type text, so i use the following pattern now : `required pattern="[a-zA-Z]"` . But how can i allow white space between approved chars?

Comment: What version of android and what browser on android?

Comment: The pattern /.*\S+.*/ allows white-space between words by default.

Comment: I know. But i have only 1 white space in the field. The problem is only for the first input field(text)

Comment: Fixed it a little bit. check my edit